# What tempering process do you use when moulding chocolates

Tags: chocolate, tempering

I want make moulded chocolate but am always having a hard time keeping the chocolate in temper for the sealing process.

I use the microwave method to temper the chocolate and I do so with a batch of about 600g. Once the chocolate is tempered, I fill the moulds with the chocolate and then empty the moulds back into the bowl of tempered chocolate. I find that when I do this the chocolate in the bowl is already setting and becoming hard.

One idea I had was to temper more chocolate so that there is more in the bowl and will keep in temper for longer. But if I do this, I will have a lot of tempered chocolate left over.

Is there a better or more efficient way to make a one-off batch of moulded chocolates?

Answer (score 1):

Either use both methods or just use the second step to maintain the temper/work-ability of your chocolate:

A) Use the double boiler method to start tempering your chocolate.

A bowl/pan of chocolate sitting above a pot of hot water - the water should not touch the bottom of the bowl/pan.

B) Dip the bottom of your tempered chocolate in hot water for a few seconds, scraping the base (and sides) of the bowl/pan, mixing it into the rest of the chocolate.  
You can repeat this step if the chocolate is not warm enough/cools down.

Of course you could look at investing in a chocolate melter.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more thoroughly?  Short answers often don't really do the work of answering a question.

Comment: Thank you, it has been edited.  However I understood the OP has some knowledge of tempering, so presumed he would not need a detailed answer.

Comment: I understand your thinking. One thing you'll learn about SE is that answers should be useful to everyone who might have similar issues, but they may not all have the same level of experience.

Comment: Ok, I see your point.  Will keep that in mind in future.